# How to run multiple functions sequentialy with multiprocessing python?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run multiple functions with multiprocessing and running into a bit of wall. I want to run an initial function to completion on all processes/inputs and then run 2 or 3 other functions in parallel on the output of the first function. I've already got my search function. the code is there for the sake of explanation.

I'm not sure how to continue the code from here. I've put my initial attempt below. I want all instances of process1 to finish and then process2 and process3 to start in parallel.

Code is something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def init(*args):
    global working_dir
    [working_dir] = args

def process1(InFile):
    python.DoStuffWith.InFile
    Output.save.in(working_dir)

def process2(queue):
    inputfiles2 = []
    python.searchfunction.appendOutputof.process1.to.inputfiles2
    python.DoStuffWith.process1.Output
    python.Output

def process3(queue):
    inputfiles2 = []
    python.searchfunction.appendOutputof.process1.to.inputfiles2
    python.DoStuffWith.process1.Output
    python.Output

def MCprocess():
    working_dir = input("enter input: ")
    inputfiles1 = []
    python.searchfunction.appendfilesin.working_dir.to.inputfiles1
    with Pool(initializer=init, initargs=[working_dir], processes=16) as pool:
        pool.map(process1, inputfiles1)
        pool.close()
    
    #Editted Code
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue
    queue.put(working_dir)
    queue.put(working_dir)
    ProcessTwo = multiprocessing.Process(target=process2, args=(queue,))
    ProcessThree = multiprocessing.Process(target=process3, args=(queue,))
    ProcessTwo.start()
    ProcessThree.start()
     #OLD CODE
     #with Pool(initializer=init, initargs=[working_dir], processes=16) as pool:
        #pool.map_async(process2)
        #pool.map_async(process3)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MCprocess()
```

Comment: As an aside, exiting the `with` closes the pool, `pool.close()` is not needed when you use a `with`.

Comment: Apart from that `map_async` misses a second parameter this looks ok. What is the problem?

Comment: The process I'm doing isn't iterable is the issue. I'm not sure what to use as the second parameter. I'm using all the output of process1 in a single process that runs in process2 and a single process that runs in process3. I want process2 and process3 to run at the same time as they can be lengthly.

Comment: If process2 and process3 should each run only in one instance, use a "Process" instead of a "Pool". Create for each of the two a "Process", start both, then join both (if you want to wait until both terminated). They will run in parallel. The functionality of "init" must somehow be integrated at the beginning of the "processN" functions.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've updated my code to use Process. But now I receive an error saying working_dir is not defined. How do I pass the value to process2/3 ? or should that be a separate question?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Added code. passed the values using a Queue. Would you like to answer the question properly so I can accept your answer?

Comment: New issue, processes 2 and 3 run before process1 is complete. should that be a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use an Event.  The first process calls `event.set()` when it is done to indicate that the event has happened.  The waiting processes use `event.wait()` or one of its variants to wait to be awoken that the event has been set.